# How to get barstate.isconfirmed (Bar confirmation hook) of higher time frame in pine script 5?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

`barstate.isconfirmed` is working nicely on chart timeframe but how would I execute a function on exactly when higher timeframe bar is closed?
`request.security(ticker,higherTimeframe,barstate.isconfirmed)`, as said in documentation, is not safe, and also `ta.change(time_close(higherTimeframe)` and similar codes are triggered when new bar is just created!

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the higher timeframe bar closes at the same time on your chart's timeframe.

```
htf_time_close = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", time_close)    
close_together = barstate.isconfirmed and (time_close == htf_time_close)
```

Comment: This works perfect if last bar of small timeframe is built and confirmed. if not we will miss confirmation of high timeframe's last candle. if there is no tick in a period of time, there is no bar in that period. this happens often in super small timeframes such 5S and 15S and when market is very calm.